# How to use saved model loader with tf.estimator for VGG16

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network, tensorflow-estimator

I'm looking to implement a FCN8, following this tutorial:
https://medium.com/nanonets/how-to-do-image-segmentation-using-deep-learning-c673cc5862ef

My code, however, is structured differently, since it's part of a bigger project. I am using the Estimator class.

My question is: how can I do what this code is doing in the Estimator class? Can I use saved_model.loader.load to load in VGG16 in my model_fn for my Estimator? Or is there some other way I can do this?

Thanks!